# Log outputs are not shown in jupyter when calling another script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook (`.ipynb`) with the following content:

```
%%bash

python log_test.py
```

which `log_test.py` is:

```
import time

print('this is first appearance...')

time.sleep(10)

print('after 10 sec sleep')

time.sleep(10)

print('after 10 sec sleep')
```

When I execute the jupyter cell it doesn't show the output directly after `print()` function and waits until the job is completely done. I would like to know is it possible to do it in some way to show the output immediately (without waiting 20 sec)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I followed this [website](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-run-python-script-py-file-in-jupyter-notebook-ipynb-file-and-ipython/)

therefore I replaced the code

```
%%bash
python log_test.py
```

with this line:

```
%run -i log_test.py
```

It printed out in real time.